# Append data to a specific element in a json file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, tuples

So, I have some information that I want to save in a json file like this dictionary:

```
dict   = { 'Group1': { 'name': 'Steve', 'surname': 'Johnson'} }
```

I want to write this dictionary to the file, so the file content will be like this:

```
{ 
'Group1': { 'name': 'Steve', 'surname': 'Johnson' }
}
```

How can I append another person to `Group1`? Something like this:

```
{ 
'Group1': [ { 'name': 'Steve', 'surname': 'Johnson' },
          { 'name': 'Maria', 'surname': 'Loinch' } ]
}
```

I want to retrieve all the info from `Group1` later with something like:

```
for name,surname in Group1:
  print name,surname
```

Comment: `d['Group1'] = [d['Group1'],{ 'name': 'Maria', 'surname': 'Loinch' }]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library :

```
import json
json.dump(your_dict, the_file)
```

But the json in the file will be a correct json, not like your:

```
{ 
"Group1": { "name": "Steve", "surname": "Johnson" }
}
```

or if you want to append elements in group1:

```
{ 
"Group1": [{ "name": "Steve", "surname": "Johnson" }]
}
```

To retrieve information :

```
your_dict = json.load(your_file)
```

For you append, you are changing the type or Group1 from dict to List/Array so make it as a list even for one element and then

```
your_dict[group1].append(new_person_dict)
```

Comment: wait a little, isn't { "Group1": { "name": "Steve", "surname": "Johnson" } } a valid json?

Comment: Do you say that because I have non minified it or did i miss something ?

Comment: Yes because i said you should declare it as a list. I modify the answer to be more clear